# GitKraken config file (Windows)

Tags: windows, git, gitkraken

Where can I find the config files for GitKraken on Windows?

GitKraken shows many repositories, which I would not like to be listed in the "recently opened repos" list.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

GitKraken saves its configuration in `%AppData%/.gitkraken`. Despite missing a file ending, all files here are JSON, so you can open them directly in a text editor. `config` for instance seems to store general settings such as window location and size.

You can remove a repo from "recently opened repos" by removing it from the `localRepoCache` in the `profiles/<random string>/` subfolder.

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot!
I also had to remove entries in config
A bit unclear for me was the "Project directory" until now. As far as I understand, all repos in this directory are shown in "recently opened repos"

Comment: Any idea where this is on Mac?

Comment: If anybody knows, feel free to edit it into the answer. :) I don't own a Mac myself.

Answer (score 0):

there's also to clean the

`Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\.gitkraken\profiles\<random string>\repoSettings`

folder to completely clean the cache

Answer (score 0):

For the mac, I found the .gitkraken in `/Users/<my-account>/`